# How can I count one-to-many relationship, but include 0's?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I essentially have 2 models:

Students
Classes

Each student can sign up for as many classes as they want. I wrote a simple query to count how many classes each student has signed up for, but cannot figure out how to include students who have chosen 0 classes. I am ultimately trying to see how many students have signed up for how many classes.

```
SELECT classes_chosen, count(*) AS student_count 
FROM (SELECT students.email, count(*) AS classes_chosen
  FROM students
  JOIN students_classes ON students_classes.student_id = students.id
  GROUP BY student_id) AS sub_q
GROUP BY classes_chosen
ORDER BY classes_chosen ASC;
```

I would like to end with something like:

```
    classes_chosen, student_count
    0, 47
    1, 35
    2, 45
    3, 85
    .
    .
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate inside `students_classes` only to get how many classes has each student chosen and then `LEFT` join `students` to the results and aggregate again:

```
SELECT COALESCE(classes_chosen, 0) classes_chosen, COUNT(*) AS student_count 
FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT student_id, COUNT(*) AS classes_chosen
  FROM students_classes 
  GROUP BY student_id
) AS c ON c.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY classes_chosen
ORDER BY classes_chosen ASC;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/euwyuiXpzhvHj8jUsTSeoB/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use `LEFT JOIN` in the subquery:

```
SELECT classes_chosen, count(*) AS student_count 
FROM (SELECT students.email, count(sc.student_id) AS classes_chosen
      FROM students s LEFT JOIN
           students_classes s
           ON sc.student_id = s.id
      GROUP BY student_id
     ) AS sub_q
GROUP BY classes_chosen
ORDER BY classes_chosen ASC;
```

Note:  If all students have a matching class, then you will not get `0` in the result set.  I interpret your question as wanting to count all students rather than particularly returning `0`.